# Remove hibernation from Linux Mint 17.3?

Tags: linux, ssd, linux-mint, hibernate

I'm trying to remove hibernation from my system because I've an SSD.
I followed the following guide: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/626

And my values now are:

```
<defaults>
     <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
     <allow_active>no</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

But when I shut down my PC I've the following options: `Shut down` `Restart` `Cancel` `Hibernate`

How can hibernation be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/mint-cinnamon-first#TOC-Disable-hibernation-suspend-to-disk-):

Copy the following command line and paste it into the terminal, in order to avoid typing errors (this is one line):

```
sudo mv -v /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla /
```

Press `Enter` and submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

With that, you've moved the settings file that enables hibernation, to the main directory `/` (root). Thus rendering it ineffective. The new location is a safe storage, from which you can retrieve it again, should you ever wish to restore hibernation.

**Reboot your computer. Hibernation should now no longer be one of the options in the shutdown menu.**